# Multiplicative complex function has mean value

Tags: complex-analysis, roots-of-unity, multiplicative-function

I came up with the following question, and I don't have proof of it.

Let $m>1$ be a positive integer. Let $f:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{C}$ a multiplicative function, whose image is a subset of the $m$-th roots of unity. Then the limit $$\lim_{N\to +\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^Nf(k)}{N}$$ exists.

Comment: What is the definition of a multiplicative function?

Comment: Oh ok, forgot to add completely. In this case, we want $f(a)f(b)=f(ab)$ for each positive integer $a$ and $b$.